# Why two different values when execute the function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don’t know why, but when I run the (kpis1) only, I get the result (100) yet when I run the (kpis2) only I get the result (97).

While running both of them the result becomes kpis1=100 but kpis2=70?

Why the function gives a correct result for single parameter, but wrong result when I put two parameters?

```
<script src="../../scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/jscript">
var isProd = true;
var MAX_PROCESS_PER_ELEMENT = 30;
var NUMBER_OF_ELEMENT = 11;
var elements = new Array(NUMBER_OF_ELEMENT);
var totalRolled = 0;
var totalDeveloped = 0;
var totalImplement = 0;
var totalCount = 0;
var totalOwners = 0;
var totalChampions = 0;
var totalAssessed = 0;
var totalItemsClosed = 0;
var totalItemsPending = 0;

var chartIm;

var colors = ["31116e", "5e646f", "009861", "005b8c", "874614", "cc202b", "b85c27", "eb8030", "005a5a", "5ca6de", "842790"];
var bgColor = "fcfdfd"; //"feeebd";
var chartAlpha = 60;

var COLUMN_NO = "ows_No";
var COLUMN_TITLE = "ows_Title";
var COLUMN_ID = "ows_ID";
var COLUMN_LINK = "ows_Link";
var COLUMN_ELEMENT = "ows_Element";
var COLUMN_OWNER = "ows_Owner";
var COLUMN_PROCESS_WEIGHT = "ows_Weight_x0025_";
var COLUMN_IMPLM_SCORE = "ows_Aduit_x0020_Score";
var COLUMN_IS_DEVELOPED = "ows_Developed";
var COLUMN_IS_ROLLED_OUT = "ows_Rolled_x0020_Out";
var COLUMN_IS_ASSESSED = "ows_Assessed";
var COLUMN_CYCLE = "ows_Assessment_x0020_Cycle";
var COLUMN_ACTION_ITEMS = "ows_Identified_x0020_GAP";
var COLUMN_LPCR = "ows_LPCR_x0020_GAPs";
var COLUMN_OTHER_GAPS = "ows_Other_x0020_GAPs";
var COLUMN_ACTION_COUNT = "ows__x0023__x0020_GAPs";
var COLUMN_ACTION_CLOSED = "ows_ClosedGaps";
var COLUMN_ACTION_PENDING = "ows_Pending_x0020_GAPs";
var COLUMN_CHAMPION = "ows_Champion";
var COLUMN_RESPONS_PERSONS = "ows_Res";
var COLUMN_RESPONS_PERSONS = "ows_Res";
var KPI_MATRIX = new Array();
var plannedEventTD = 0;
var doneEventTD = 0;
var alertMessage;

function loadSmsXmlData(sSmsXml2) {

        var sSmsXml = "https://sharepoint.com/orgs/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?";
        sSmsXml += "Cmd=Display&XMLDATA=TRUE&Query=*?&List="+sSmsXml2;
        $.ajax({ url: (isProd ? sSmsXml : "sms.xml"),
            type: "POST", dataType: "xml",async: false,
            data: "", cache: false ,
            contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",cache:false
            ,complete: processSmsResult
            ,error: function(xml,status,msg) {alert("Error in Loading the SMS Process Data \n error code:" + msg)} 
    });

 var out = [totalImplement,"Total Implement"];
alert(out);
return out;

function processSmsResult(xData, status) {

    $(xData.responseXML).children(1).children(1).children().each(function () {
        var currentElement;
        if (!isNaN($(this).attr(COLUMN_NO))) {

            var elementNo = parseInt($(this).attr(COLUMN_NO), 10);

            if (elements[elementNo - 1] == undefined) {
                var currentElement = new Element();
                currentElement.no = elementNo;
                currentElement.champion = $(this).attr(COLUMN_CHAMPION);
                currentElement.title = $(this).attr(COLUMN_ELEMENT);
                elements[elementNo - 1] = currentElement;
            }
            else { currentElement = elements[elementNo - 1] };
            var process = new Process();
            process.no = parseFloat($(this).attr(COLUMN_NO)).toFixed(2);
            if ($(this).attr(COLUMN_ACTION_CLOSED))
                process.actionClosed = parseInt($(this).attr(COLUMN_ACTION_CLOSED).substring($(this).attr(COLUMN_ACTION_CLOSED).indexOf("#") + 1), 10);
            if ($(this).attr(COLUMN_ACTION_COUNT))
                process.actionCount = parseInt($(this).attr(COLUMN_ACTION_COUNT), 10);
            if ($(this).attr(COLUMN_ACTION_ITEMS))
                process.ActionItems = $(this).attr(COLUMN_ACTION_ITEMS);
            if ($(this).attr(COLUMN_ACTION_PENDING))
                process.actionPending = parseInt($(this).attr(COLUMN_ACTION_PENDING), 10);
            if ($(this).attr(COLUMN_CYCLE))
                process.cycle = $(this).attr(COLUMN_CYCLE);
            if ($(this).attr(COLUMN_ID))
                process.id = parseInt($(this).attr(COLUMN_ID), 10);
            if ($(this).attr(COLUMN_IS_ASSESSED))
            if ($(this).attr(COLUMN_IS_ASSESSED).length > 5)
                process.isAssessed = $(this).attr(COLUMN_IS_ASSESSED).substring(0, $(this).attr(COLUMN_IS_ASSESSED).lastIndexOf(" "));
            if ($(this).attr(COLUMN_IMPLM_SCORE))
                process.implmScore = parseInt(parseFloat($(this).attr(COLUMN_IMPLM_SCORE)) * 100, 10);
            if ($(this).attr(COLUMN_IS_DEVELOPED))
                process.isDeveloped = $(this).attr(COLUMN_IS_DEVELOPED);
            if ($(this).attr(COLUMN_IS_ROLLED_OUT))
                process.isRolledout = $(this).attr(COLUMN_IS_ROLLED_OUT);
            if ($(this).attr(COLUMN_ACTION_COUNT))
                process.actionCount = parseInt($(this).attr(COLUMN_ACTION_COUNT), 10);
            if ($(this).attr(COLUMN_ACTION_ITEMS))
                process.actionItems = $(this).attr(COLUMN_ACTION_ITEMS);
            if ($(this).attr(COLUMN_LINK))
                process.link = $(this).attr(COLUMN_LINK).substring(0, $(this).attr(COLUMN_LINK).indexOf(", "));
            if ($(this).attr(COLUMN_LPCR))
                process.LPCR = $(this).attr(COLUMN_LPCR);
            if ($(this).attr(COLUMN_OTHER_GAPS))
                process.otherGaps = $(this).attr(COLUMN_OTHER_GAPS);
            if ($(this).attr(COLUMN_PROCESS_WEIGHT))
                process.processWeight = (parseInt(parseFloat($(this).attr(COLUMN_PROCESS_WEIGHT).substring($(this).attr(COLUMN_PROCESS_WEIGHT).indexOf("#") + 1) * 100), 10));
            if ($(this).attr(COLUMN_TITLE))
                process.title = $(this).attr(COLUMN_TITLE);
            if ($(this).attr(COLUMN_TITLE))
                process.owner = $(this).attr(COLUMN_OWNER).replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
            if ($(this).attr(COLUMN_RESPONS_PERSONS))
                process.responsPersons = $(this).attr(COLUMN_RESPONS_PERSONS);
            process.implmScore = process.implmScore - (3*process.actionPending);
            currentElement.processes[parseInt(process.no.toString().substring(process.no.toString().indexOf(".") + 1), 10)] = process;
            process.scoreToElement = process.processWeight * process.implmScore / 100;
            currentElement.itemsClosed += process.actionClosed;
            currentElement.itemsPending += process.actionPending;
            totalItemsClosed += process.actionClosed;
            totalItemsPending += process.actionPending;
            currentElement.processesCount++;
            currentElement.implementation += process.scoreToElement;
            currentElement.fullScore += process.processWeight;
            if (process.isAssessed.toUpperCase().length > 6)
                currentElement.assessedProcesses++;
            if (process.isDeveloped.toUpperCase().indexOf("YES") > -1)
                currentElement.developedProcesses++;
            if (process.isRolledout.toUpperCase().indexOf("YES") > -1)
                currentElement.rolledoutProcesses++;
        } 

    });                    

        $(elements).each(function () {
        totalCount += this.processesCount;
        totalRolled += this.rolledoutProcesses;
        totalDeveloped += this.developedProcesses;
        totalAssessed += this.assessedProcesses;
        this.implementation = 100 * this.implementation / this.fullScore;
        totalImplement += this.implementation;
    });
      totalImplement /= NUMBER_OF_ELEMENT;

} 

function Element() {
    this.no = 0;
    this.title = "";
    this.champion = "";
    this.processesCount = 0;
    this.rolledoutProcesses = 0;
    this.developedProcesses = 0;
    this.assessedProcesses = 0;
    this.itemsClosed = 0;
    this.itemsPending = 0;
    this.implementation = 0;
    this.fullScore = 0;
    this.processes = new Array(MAX_PROCESS_PER_ELEMENT);
}
function Process() {
    this.title = "";
    this.id = -1;
    this.no = 0;
    this.link = "#";
    this.owner = "";
    this.processWeight = 0;
    this.scoreToElement = 0; 
    this.implmScore = 0;
    this.isDeveloped = "";
    this.isRolledout = "";
    this.isAssessed = "";
    this.cycle = "";
    this.ActionItems = "N/A";
    this.LPCR = "";
    this.otherGaps = "";
    this.actionCount = 0;
    this.actionClosed = 0;
    this.actionPending = 0;
    this.responsPersons = "(set)";
}
}
```

```
 kpis1 =  loadSmsXmlData("%7B474EAAB5%2D25F5%2D4669%2DB677%2DB85587EA40CA%7D");
 alert ("kpis1: "+ kpis1[0]);
 kpis2 =  loadSmsXmlData("%7B0EE4A087%2DDAF4%2D49F5%2DB4DF%2D413AF23B6C7C%7D");
 alert ("kpis2: "+ kpis2[0]);
```

Here is my jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gs8sxean/2/

Comment: Code note: You can shorten code like: `if ($(this).attr(COLUMN_TITLE)) process.title = $(this).attr(COLUMN_TITLE);` to just `process.title = $(this).attr(COLUMN_TITLE) || process.title` and drop all the ifs. Some of the more complex operations need to be different, but for the simple *check and assign* this may help :)

Comment: You actually have a number of problems with the code shown. I have outlined some alternative suggestions below, but you need to fix the basic problems too (like you are not returning results from your functions, but have written the code to expect return values!)

Comment: You should not offer financial rewards on SO (edited out). Instead, start trying the suggestions below and feedback where your remaining problems are :)

Comment: dear   TrueBlueAussie... I am still testing your solutions. I will response to you once I am done with the test. however, I appreciate your answer and support, and I hope this will help me...

Answer (score 0):

It's because in your `processSmsResult` function, you're modifying the global variable `totalImplement` so in the subsequent call to the same function, will have different values of that variable. That's the reason why you're getting two different outputs.

Another thing to notice is:

```
 var out = [totalImplement,"Total Implement"];
alert(out);
return out;
```

This snippet should be inside your `processSmsResult` function at the end. Because you're modifying the response data in the success callback of the ajax function which is async in nature.

Comment: While this answers the obvious question *asked*, I think you can assume you need to show *how* to do it correctly too :)

Comment: Although they shouldn't, they are using `async: false` so this is not relevant.

Comment: thank you Mohammed... by tring you solution, now I have different reslut. 1st the (kpis1) always correct, but now the reslut of 2ed paramter (kpis2) become different than what I usually get, but still not correct

Comment: I love you soooo much @mohamedrias, your solution is correct. please give me more time to test it and I will get back to you. many many thanks mohammed. I might response to you tomorrow, becuse I need to take a rest after long thinking. but would you please explain to me the problem why you moved the function up...

Answer (score 0):

There are loads of issues to resolve in your code:

- Once indented properly, it is apparent your functions are actually nested, but they cannot work that way.
- You must absolutely get rid of `async: false` as that leads to more problems than it solves! Then you will have the case of trying to use the returned data from an asynchronous operation, immediately after starting it, but not waiting for the results. This is like "ordering a Pizza then trying to eat it before it is delivered" :)
- You need to either use callbacks with your functions, or use jQuery promises. Callbacks are easier to understand but promises are a cleaner option.
- You are expecting return results from your functions, but your functions do not return anything.
- You do not use `status` in your processing function, so do not pass it.

Assuming `processSmsResult` is not an async operation too, you can pattern it like this:

### Callback version:

```
function loadSmsXmlData(sSmsXml2, callback) {

    var sSmsXml = "https://sharepoint.com/orgs/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?";
    sSmsXml += "Cmd=Display&XMLDATA=TRUE&Query=*?&List="+sSmsXml2;
    $.ajax({ url: (isProd ? sSmsXml : "sms.xml"),
        type: "POST", dataType: "xml",
        data: "", cache: false ,
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",cache:false
        ,complete: callback
        ,error: function(xml,status,msg) {alert("Error in Loading the SMS Process Data \n error code:" + msg)} 
});
```

And use like this:

```
loadSmsXmlData("%7B474EAAB5%2D25F5%2D4669%2DB677%2DB85587EA40CA%7D", function(data, status){
            var kpis = processSmsResult(data);
            // Now you can alert the result of this operation
        });
```

### Promises version:

```
// Simple return the $.ajaz promise
function loadSmsXmlData(sSmsXml2, callback) {

    var sSmsXml = "https://sharepoint.com/orgs/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?";
    sSmsXml += "Cmd=Display&XMLDATA=TRUE&Query=*?&List="+sSmsXml2;
    return $.ajax({ url: (isProd ? sSmsXml : "sms.xml"),
        type: "POST", dataType: "xml",
        data: "", cache: false ,
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",cache:false
});
```

and use like this:

```
loadSmsXmlData("%7B474EAAB5%2D25F5%2D4669%2DB677%2DB85587EA40CA%7D").done(function (function (data) {
        kpis = processSmsResult(data);
        // Now you can alert the result of this operation
}).fail(function (hdr, textStatus) {
        alert("Error in Loading the SMS Process Data \n error code:" + textStatus)
});
```

The last problem was caused by trying to assign the result of a function to a variable, e.g. `kpis1 =  loadSmsXmlData`, but that function does not return anything so neither should work.

in the async world you want to wait for both to succeed, either sequentially or in parallel. So change the use to be something like this:

```
var load1 = loadSmsXmlData("%7B474EAAB5%2D25F5%2D4669%2DB677%2DB85587EA40CA%7D");
var load2 = loadSmsXmlData("%7B0EE4A087%2DDAF4%2D49F5%2DB4DF%2D413AF23B6C7C%7D");
$.when(load1, load2).done(function(data1, data2){
    // both complete, process the results
    var kpis1 = processSmsResult(data1);
    var kpis2 = processSmsResult(data2);
}).fail(function(hdr, textStatus){
    alert("Error in Loading the SMS Process Data \n error code:" + textStatus)
});
```

### Other issues:

You need your functions to perform self-contained operations. One of the things to avoid is the use of any global variables as that introduces dependencies.

You could for instance change you `processSmsResult` function to actually return your result.

Comment: this is what I got when I run your secript>>>SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'when'

Comment: @Khalil: What version of jQuery are you using? it was added in 1.5: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

Comment: it is ((jquery-1.4.4.min.js))... sorry, I was not able to add this version because it is not in the list of jsfiddle

Comment: @Khalil: Very important detail as your jQuery is *way too old*. Can you update your jQuery (recommended you go to 1.11.2 for HTML 4 compatibility)? If not, you will need to use the callback option instead.

Comment: I have selected version 1.4.4 because this is the stable version for me. I will try version 1.11.2 and I will get back to you.

Comment: after I updated it to 1.11.2, I always get this worning>>> Error in Loading the SMS Process Data/error code: No Transport.

Comment: I managed myself and fixed the above error (No Transport) but unfortunatily no result coming at all!!! however, this is my last update in jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gs8sxean/5/     (waiting for your advise)